# Initialization methods

Tags: objective-c, ios

i have a MyObject. when my program runs, i create a new MyObject

```
self.myObject = [[MyObject alloc] initWithStuff:stuff];
```

later in my code, i need to create a new MyObject.

my question is, do i need to create a new MyObject with an "init" method?

```
.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyObject : NSObject
{}

-(id)initWithStuff:(NSString *)stuff;
-(id)initWithNewStuff:(NSString *)newStuff;

-(id)newObjectWithStuff:(NSString *)newStuff;

@end

.m

-(id)initWithStuff:(NSString *)stuff;
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.myStuff = stuff;
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithNewStuff:(NSString *)newStuff;{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.myStuff = newStuff;
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)newObjectWithStuff:(NSString *)newStuff;
{
    self.myStuff = newStuff;

    return self;
}
```

or can i use a non-init method to create it?

in my code:

```
self.myObject = [[MyObject alloc] initWithNewStuff:newStuff];
```

or

```
self.myObject = [self.myObject newObjectWithStuff:newStuff];
```

i guess my question boils down to: what does

```
if (self = [super init])
```

do?

working with other objects such as dictionaries, i know "NSDictionary *myDict = myOtherDict" is perfect valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name your custom initializers as you want, but there's a convention to start your initializer method with "init".

In examples you wrote, the objects are a subclass of `NSObject` the the root class of all hierarchies. The keyword `super` refers to the class above in the hierarchy (your class's superclass), so basically, you're calling the `init` method of `NSObject` which creates and initializes an object right after memory has been allocated for it (that's what `alloc` method does). Then, you check if the method returned an object and initialize your own properties.

Take a look at this guide and make sure you understand everything what is in there https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/introduction/introobjectivec.html .

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling

```
self.myObject = [self.myObject newObjectWithStuff:newStuff];
```

you just making reference on an existing memory location. If you really want a new object You should call like

```
self.myObject = [[MyObject alloc] initWithNewStuff:newStuff];
```

The alloc key word allocates memory for a variable